# Formating an Object to All Array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

The question is pretty simple and has no clear response. I have an object my goal is to take each value and key transform them to object and push to the array, for example below to make it clear.

```js
{
  title: "This is a Title",
  name: "This is a name"
}
```

Transform to.

```js
[
  {title: "This is a Title"},
  {name: "This is a name"}
]
```

Comment: Don't do it it's not a valid structure.

Comment: this is to make a query in sequelize those gonna be params so yes it is for sequelize.

Comment: If you share what you have tried, you might receive better response

Comment: @ArsalanAkhtar: How is that data structure invalid?

Comment: [
  {title: "This is a Title",
  name: "This is a name"}
]

Comment: @ArsalanAkhtar: It's not an _invalid_ data structure, and there may be a good reason why the OP wants it that way. It's perfectly valid JS.

Comment: @Cerbus what is your approach to using in your code first one or second one. I said it's not a valid structure. do you use that approach?

Comment: Maybe @learningReact can use .map function to get what properties are needed.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert the object to an array, then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to an array of objects in the format you want:

```js
const obj = {
  title: "This is a Title",
  name: "This is a name"
};

const arr = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the entries of the object by using any entry for a new object.

```js
const
    data = { title: "This is a Title", name: "This is a name" },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(e => Object.fromEntries([e]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the response thanks man, Validating it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Love how clean the existing solutions are, but if you need to handle high amounts of data, a solution like this will provide much better performance:

```js
function transform(obj) {
    let arr = []

    for (let key in obj) {
        let temp = {}

        temp[key] = obj[key]

        arr.push(temp)
    }

    return arr
}

let data = {
    title: "This is a Title",
    name: "This is a name"
}

console.log(transform(data))
```

Edit: Figured out how to use code snippets :)

Comment: This can be shortened a little: `arr.push({ [key]: obj[key] })`. That might even be faster, as well.

Comment: That would definitely make it cleaner, but results in worse performance for some reason. The difference is about 20% in FF91 and even more in Chrome.

It might be preferable in some cases tho, since i feel like it is easier to read.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! I guess code like that is harder to optimize for the compiler... That said, I doubt the performance difference in there is going to be significant, unless you're talking billions of records.

Comment: True, i doubt it would make any difference in real world applications. It is noticeable from like a million iterations of that for loop. But who knows what OP is up to, maybe he needs that extra bit of performance.